# How can I find ALL the shortest routes of a directed unweighted graph?

Tags: javascript, depth-first-search, dijkstra

Disclaimer: This is for a challange. I do not need the full solution to the problem but I seem to do something wrong as my program takes forever to finish.

The task is formulated as follows:

> A family wants to travel by bus. Their gas however won't be enough for the whole route. One of the kids says that it wants to stop only when necessary as to arrive faster. The other kid suggest to save some money by visiting the cheapest gas stations.
>
> They finally agree on visiting as few gas stations as possible BUT if there are multiple options they want to have the cheapest one. Below is one of the text files. It's contents are: **Liter per Kilometer, max Liter, current Liter, km from start to destination, total amount of possible gas stations and the gas stations**. Each gas station consist of: **km from start to station, price per liter**.
>
> https://bwinf.de/fileadmin/user_upload/BwInf/2019/38/1._Runde/Material/A4/fahrt2.txt

I began by finding all the routes with the fewest stops.. That however isn't working so well.. My code for finding all the cheapest routes is taking forever to finish (but works for fewer gas stations):

```
const generateFullPaths = (path) => {
    var last = path[path.length - 1];
    var next = this.reachable.get(last);

    if (path.length > minStops) { return }
    if (next.length) {
        for (var i = next.length-1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
            var newPath = path.concat([next[i]]);
            generateFullPaths(newPath);
        }
    } else {
        if (path.length < minStops) {
            minStops = path.length;
            fullPaths = [path];
        }
        else {
            fullPaths.push(path);
        }
    }
}
var minStops = Infinity;
generateFullPaths([startingNode]);
```

I have already looked into other algorithms but neither dijkstra nor bfs seem fit imho and the one I am currently using is way to slow.
You can find my slightly modified full program on https://jsfiddle.net/1fnh5oy6/